# Android YouTube API Code only loads one video

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-studio-3.0, android-youtube-api

```
private lateinit var youtubePLayerInit: YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener
private fun openTrailer(videoId: String) {
    val dialog = Dialog(this)
    val trailerDialogBinding =  DialogTrailerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    dialog.setContentView(trailerDialogBinding.root)
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

    val youtubeApiKey = "xxxxx"

    youtubePLayerInit = object: YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
        override fun onInitializationSuccess(
            p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
            p1: YouTubePlayer?,
            p2: Boolean
        ) {
            p1?.loadVideo(videoId)
        }
        override fun onInitializationFailure(
            p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
            p1: YouTubeInitializationResult?
        ) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Video Failed to Load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    trailerDialogBinding.vvMovieTrailer.initialize(youtubeApiKey, youtubePLayerInit)
    dialog.show()
    trailerDialogBinding.btnExit.setOnClickListener {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Thing is that video loads only one time, when I reload the video then dismissing the `dialog`. It doesn't load, then after like 3 or 4 times of loading, the app crashes with the errors of :

```
E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Embed config is not supported in RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.
E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Error screen presenter should be present
```

I call this video about 3 times, but only the video only loads one time. How can I fix this?